# Average of a column in sql table

Tags: sql-server

I have got the result set from another table.
QUERY on Parent Table:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Result) AS [Counts]
FROM ParentTable
GROUP BY Type
```

Result:

```
=============== 
TYPE  |  Counts 
=============== 
Type1  | 43 
Type2  | 13 
Type3  | 16
```

I need the output to be in the following format...

```
===============================   
TYPE   | COUNTs  | [Percentage]     
===============================    
Type1  | 43        |   59.72 
Type2  | 13        |   18.06 
Type3  | 16        |   22.22
```

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Comment: P.S. That is not the average...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  You can do:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Result) AS [Counts],
       COUNT(Result) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(Result)) OVER () as ratio
FROM ParentTable
GROUP BY Type ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
SUM(COUNT(Result))
I can't perform an aggregate function which already contains an aggregate

Comment: @HarishKothuri . . . That now has the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it; I change COUNT to SUM only to Simplify the answer.

```
  declare @ParentTable as table (Type char(5) , Result int)  
    INSERT @ParentTable (Type, Result) values 
    ('Type1' , 43 ),
    ('Type2' , 13 ),
    ('Type3' , 16 )




     SELECT Type, 
SUM(Result) OVER ( PARTITION BY Type)  AS [Counts] , 
Round(Cast(SUM(Result) OVER ( PARTITION BY Type) as float)  /  Cast(SUM(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) as float) * 100. ,2) Percentage
        FROM @ParentTable


Type  Counts      Percentage
----- ----------- ----------------------
Type1 43          59.72
Type2 13          18.06
Type3 16          22.22
```